# How to fetch data from SOAP WebService in Swift

Tags: swift, xml-parsing

I need to get data from SOAP WebService in Swift `https://codedump.io/share/JDHdwpOOmqne/1/swift-2-soap-web-service-call`
I tried the procedures in the referred link but it was not working,Can any one help wit a working code.

Answer (score 0):

You can use SWXML library for get data from soap web service this is easy to use and simple see the code below.

```
Alamofire.request(.GET, is_URL)
            .responseJSON { response in
                    let xmls = SWXMLHash.parse(response.data!)
                    func enumerate(indexer: XMLIndexer, level: Int) {
                        for child in indexer.children {
                            let name:String? = child.element!.name
                            print("\(level) \(name)")
                            // Take Link from XML data here 
                            if name! == "link" {
                                let text = child.element!.text
                                if text?.isEmpty == false{
                                   print(text)
                                  // Finish here Process
                                  completion(result: text!)
                                }
                            }
                            enumerate(child, level: level + 1)
                        }
                    }
                enumerate(xmls, level: 0)
            }
       }
```

And i having demo link also for this related [code for Soap parsing Demo](https://github.com/ANSCoder/Weather-App-Demo)